# LINQ to Sql performance using multiple LIKE's vs using a List

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

I have an MVC autocomplete that will search for any number of strings entered into a textbox to find an address.

For example, if they enter John Doe New York, my query will do a LIKE on all the columns in the customer table (first, last, address, city, state, zip) to see if it matches the term.  Then will move to the next search word and do the same.

My question is, is it better to hit the Sql Server DB 4 times (in this example) doing LIKE's for each search term for each field, or would it be better to return approx 10,000 rows and search them in memory as a List?

The first would require a lot more DB I/O as it searches the tables, but the 2nd would require a lot more data coming into the app.

None of the data in the Customers table is full text search indexed and, at best, would have a SQL Index on the individual columns.

Comment: Don't return 10,000 rows from the DB to the web app. The database is designed to deal with the IO and the data filtering you need done. The web server/app isn't.

Comment: In your example you specify "John Doe New York" equating to 4 db hits. Why is this? What is the criteria that determines how often the database is called? I did something similar a few years ago and I basically had a timer set up which queried the database for whatever search terms I had in the text box every second (I think).

Comment: It would query for John, then query for Doe, then for New, then for York.  Each one of these would run a query in the DB.  I tried to run the entire thing as an IQueryable, but it crashed because it created too many cartesians or something.

Comment: Ok, so you type in the string and submit that? If it's autocomplete how does it know when you're finished typing any specific term? Either way, the filtering work would be far more efficient in the database than the web app.

Comment: It waits 250ms after the typing has stopped before it submits the search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**general part**

it is better to have DB do its job

if you go with 4 queries approach you will have:

1. time for each query, let it be 6 comparisons for each row for 1 word, 6*4 comparisons, let call it 24*q1 (q1 - average number of rows)
2. time to transmit 4 results, let it be q2*4 (q2 - average number of filtered rows)
3. time to merge/filter results on client side, which actually be almost the same as p1 - 24 comparisons for each row, again 24*q2

if you go with fully db approach, you will have

1. time one query will be, 6 comparisons for 4 words = 24 comparisons for each row
2. time to transmit one result q2_filtered (q2_filtered < q2)

`24*q1 + q2*4 + 24*q2 > 24*q1 + q2_filtered` so, the answer is obvious - database should filter records

if you want to store whole customer table in memory - of course it will be faster to perform your own search which will take 24*q1, so you're getting rid of only transmission part, but it will consume web servers memory and you will have problems with synchronization between memory/db

**some details**

depending on how do you use like - you can have very different performance problems, for example `like 'ABC%'` will use index, but `like '%ABC%'` cannot use index

here are possible some tricks, like this one: concatenation of all columns into 1, sorting of symbols in it and remove duplicates, storing symbols in different columns, the same for words - this will help a bit as it can use indexes, but you will have some false positive matches

if you really need to fetch data fast - use full text indexes or special approaches to this really huge and global problem